# Unable to load PDF from url

Tags: java, selenium, pdfbox

I am using selenium and i want to read a content from pdf which is open in url

```
String url=https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=e6c1c73dfd2e4e42b806f414f41ae6cd&key=574dda953a7bd92e0ab217d1a637d88b41926aab6033dee85660d385b335ac86

try {
        String pdfContent = readPdfContent(url);
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Test Kumar"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("XXXXX"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

below is the function which is call above  error coming-'The method load(BufferedInputStream) is undefined for the type PDDocument'

```
public static  String readPdfContent(String url) throws IOException {
    
    URL pdfUrl = new URL(url);
    InputStream in = pdfUrl.openStream();
    BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(bf);
    int numberOfPages = getPageCount(doc);
    System.out.println("The total number of pages "+numberOfPages);
    String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
    doc.close();    
return content;
```

}

```
public static int getPageCount(PDDocument doc) {
//get the total number of pages in the pdf document
int pageCount = doc.getNumberOfPages();
return pageCount;
```

}

help me for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that the pdfbox jar files are in your classpath a runtime.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you import wrong library.
If you have a `maven` project, add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.24</version>
</dependency>
```

and `imported` libraries:

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Comment: now i get this error-::java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;

Comment: It's about the version, I think you have to find a compatible version for your project, you can find it throw: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox

Comment: Thanks it working but how can i verify that it contains correct text to verify actually i am contains wrong text that should not be there in pdf it show me error but it pass my test case

Comment: @ankushsingh ur welcome, don't forget the point and check it as the right answer for others to use... also I didn't get your question, can you explain it more clear!

Comment: my question is this if i enter incorrect text in code to verify that pdf contains that actual text but my test case is pass. how that to be verify it contains acutal text in pdf. beacuse i  am enter wron text to verify so it should throws be error but it doesn't